# Is there a way to crop only the design from a the canvas and ignoring all the white/transparent space?

Tags: fabricjs

I have a canvas built using **fabricJS** with the dimension of `600x500`. I have added an image to this canvas which is of size `200x300` and also a text element just below it.

```
$canvasObj.toDataURL();
```

exports the whole canvas area including the white spaces surrounding the design on the canvas.

Is there a way to get the cropped output of the design on the canvas alone instead of all the whitespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by cloning objects to a group, getting the group boundingRect, and then passing the boundingRect parameters to toDataUrl() function (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xq0m142h/1/)).

e.g.

```
// make a new group
var myGroup = new fabric.Group();
canvas.add(myGroup);

// ensure originX/Y 'center' is being used, as text uses left/top by default.
myGroup.set({ originX: 'center', originY: 'center' });

// put canvas things in new group
var i = canvas.getObjects().length;
while (i--) {
 var objType = canvas.item(i).get('type');
 if (objType==="image" || objType==="text" || objType==="itext" || objType==="rect") {

  var clone = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.item(i));
  myGroup.addWithUpdate(clone).setCoords();

  // remove original lone object
  canvas.remove(canvas.item(i));
 }
}

canvas.renderAll();

// get bounding rect for new group
var i = canvas.getObjects().length;
while (i--) {
 var objType = canvas.item(i).get('type');
 if (objType==="group") {
  var br = canvas.item(i).getBoundingRect();
 }
}

fabric.log('cropped png dataURL: ', canvas.toDataURL({
    format: 'png',
    left: br.left,
    top: br.top,
    width: br.width,
    height: br.height
}));
```

**p.s.** I should probably mention that i've not worked with image types, so i just guessed that it's called 'image'..

Comment: If you have an element that is like a wrapper for other element or where you place other elements (For example a tshirt design) you can just `getBoundingRect()` on the element and use it instead of creating a group.. Hope this make sense to someone. This is perfect in many cases though

Answer (score 0):

You can just merge all object's bounding-boxes into one, something like (I know, code is a bit ugly but it explains the main idea):

```js
function getCanvasContentBoundingBox() {
    // get array of all objects on canvas...
    const objects = canvas.getObjects();

    // nothing to return
    if (objects.length === 0) {
        return null;
    }

    const firstObjectRect = objects[0]?.getBoundingRect()!;

    // init contentsBoundingBox with boundingBox of first (and only?) object
    const contentsBoundingBox = {
        left: firstObjectRect.left,
        top: firstObjectRect.top,
        right: firstObjectRect.left + firstObjectRect.width,
        bottom: firstObjectRect.top + firstObjectRect.height,
    };

    objects.forEach( (obj) => {
        const objRect = obj.getBoundingRect();
        const objRight = objRect.left + objRect.width;
        const objBottom = objRect.top + objRect.height;

        // if object is outside calculated "contentsBoundingBox", update it:
        if (objRect.left < contentsBoundingBox.left) {
            contentsBoundingBox.left = objRect.left;
        }
        if (objRect.top < contentsBoundingBox.top) {
            contentsBoundingBox.top = objRect.top;
        }
        if (objRight > contentsBoundingBox .right) {
            contentsBoundingBox.right = objRight;
        }
        if (objBottom > contentsBoundingBox .bottom) {
            contentsBoundingBox.bottom = objBottom;
        }
    });

    return {
        ...contentsBoundingBox,
        width: contentsBoundingBox.right - contentsBoundingBox.left,
        height: contentsBoundingBox.bottom - contentsBoundingBox.top,
    }
}
```

and then just:

```js
const crop = getCanvasContentBoundingBox();
if (!crop) {
    return;
} 
const blobUrl = canvas.toDataURL({
    format: 'png',
    quality: 1,
    multiplier: 1 / canvas.getZoom(),

    left: crop.left,
    top: crop.top,
    width: crop.width,
    height: crop.height,
});
```